# Angular 7 service worker acting weird

Tags: angular, angular7, service-worker, angular-service-worker

We are building an Angular 7 app at the moment and decided to also integrate Angular service worker to get some PWA benefits. So far so good.
It was working great (at least we thought) and the site was loading a lot faster (it still does).

However, the cached version is not at all accurate and therefore doesn't apply any new code release unless we force a refresh (which we can't ask our clients to do). A regular page refresh doesn't do anything.

Worst, even after a forced refresh, at the moment we can see the new version but if we go on the website few days laters, the worker is loading again an older version of the app (a few releases older code but never the same, somehow it's like it was updating it but with a delay)

Note that to implement the worker, we followed step by step the guide at https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started

Also, we don't have any error in the console.

Here is our config file:

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

We use:

```
Angular 7.2.0
@angular/service-worker: ~7.2.0
```

We're new to this so not sure where to start investigating but any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: pls check your server which runs your app if it serves the ngsw-worker.json correctly. Since it is a static resource, I forgot to add the json extension to the static resource extension list. You can check it on console navigation tab if it loads the proper one. And you can check the server time if it is set correctly on which you build, it may cause some sliding. For now, i have this ideas.

Comment: Try adding `updateMode: "prefetch"` to the app `assetGroup`. Perhaps this [article](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-service-worker/) will help you better understand the cache mechanism.

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers. I'll try that and get back at you to let you know (might take 1-2 days)

Comment: The guide you followed clearly states `The service worker installed the updated version of your app in the background, and the next time the page is loaded or reloaded, the service worker switches to the latest version.` which is the behavior you are describing.

I believe this could solve your problem https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-communications

Comment: @JohanFaerch read again my question, `unless we force a refresh.....A regular page refresh doesn't do anything.`

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever into the dist folder after building your production build? A bunch of hashed files? These files are unique because of hashing, So whenever you build your angular app you'll see the same files added with a hash which makes the browser to consider them as new / Updated file.

For example:

> if you have a file `scripts.88543e05931e3c6ffbb0.js` in your first
>   build, then the next build won't have the same hash, the file might be
>   named like `scripts.90921e05931e3c6fe220.js`.

But the problem is index.html is not having any hash. So if it is stored in your cache, the possibilities of your browser know that there is a change in the application is very less, So you have two options either not to store `index.html`in the browser cache, Or by clearing the stored cache by triggering a notification from your server for new update in code and make the user to make a click event and reload the page.

For method 1 use,

```
 <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"/>
```

this will make index.html not to get stored in your browser